# jython calling command from child script

Tags: python, jython

I have a parent and a child script. I am trying a command (WLST nmConnect) from the child script but I got a "NameError: nmConnect" error message when I tried.
The strange thing is that I can call it from the parent script! So I think the system variables (e.g. CLASSPATH) are not passed to the child script?

parent script

```
import wl
...
wlmanager = wl.WeblogicManager()
...
if not wlmanager.connect_to_nodemanager(ssl, domainName, userConfigFile, userKeyFile):
....
```

child script

```
def connect_to_nodemanager(self, p_ssl, p_domainName, p_userConfigFile, p_userKeyFile):
try:
    nmConnect(domainName=p_domainName,userConfigFile=p_userConfigFile,userKeyFile=p_userKeyFile)
    return True
except:
    ...
    return False
```

So when I put the nmConnect to the parent script, it worked...
Could you please help?

Thanks, V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the next import:

```
from wlstModule import *
```

it is not needed in the parent but it is in the child.